# Averaging predicted probabilities of a bagged tree

Tags: r, rstudio

using weather data from package rattle.data I have tried writing a script for a bagged tree classification, where RainTomorrow is the target column, followingly

```
if(!require(rpart)) install.packages("rpart") 
if(!require(rpart.plot)) install.packages("rpart.plot") 
if(!require(caret)) install.packages("caret") 
if(!require(rattle.data)) install.packages("rattle.data") 
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse") 
if(!require(ipred)) install.packages("ipred") 
if(!require(Metrics)) install.packages("Metrics") 
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(rattle.data)
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(ipred)
library(Metrics)

set.seed(500)

data <- weather

# cleaning data
data <-
  data %>%
  mutate(month = months(Date)) %>% 
  select(-Date, -Location, -RISK_MM) %>% 
  mutate(RainTomorrow = as.factor(ifelse(RainTomorrow == "No", 0, 1))) %>% 
  na.omit()

# creating train and test data
index <- createDataPartition(data$RainTomorrow, p = .6, list = FALSE)
train_data <- data[ index, ]
test_data <- data[-index, ]

# creating models

bagged_tree <- bagging(formula = RainTomorrow ~ ., 
                        data = train_data,
                        coob = TRUE)

pred_bagg_class <- predict(object = bagged_tree ,    
                            newdata = test_data,  
                            type = "class") 

# predictions on the test set
pred_bagg <- predict(object = bagged_tree,
                newdata = test_data,
                type = "prob")
```

now what I need is **averaging all predicted probabilities and then choosing the class that has maximum probability**, but I always get back 0.5 (if I run the mean() or rowMeans() function on pred_bagg), which is obviously not correct, am I missing something important?

Comment: I seriously doubt this code can be cut and pasted into a session and have it run. Suggest you include necessary library calls and setup code.

Comment: ah yes, my bad, included all the necessary (and unnecessary) packages. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, if you need to find mean of all the predicted values then you probably need this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(pred_bagg_class) - 1)
df <- cbind(df, pred_bagg)
df$pred_mean <- rowMeans(df)
```

Which would give you:

```
 df
    as.numeric(pred_bagg_class) - 1    0    1 pred_mean
1                                 0 0.76 0.24 0.3333333
2                                 0 0.72 0.28 0.3333333
3                                 0 1.00 0.00 0.3333333
4                                 0 1.00 0.00 0.3333333
5                                 0 0.96 0.04 0.3333333
6                                 0 0.96 0.04 0.3333333
7                                 1 0.28 0.72 0.6666667
8                                 0 0.76 0.24 0.3333333
9                                 0 0.56 0.44 0.3333333
10                                0 0.84 0.16 0.3333333
11                                1 0.24 0.76 0.6666667
```

But, if you use `rowMeans` on `pred_bagg` then you would always get 0.5 because `pred_bagg` has individual probabilities of each class of target variable which adds up to 1 for each row and if you take a mean of it, it would give you 0.5 for each row every time.